# Create trigger and send emails

Tags: db2

I have to create a db2 triggers and I need to check one of the inserted values and base on this checking i need to take a send email action 
let us consider the below table for example 
ID         NAME        TransactionID     needapproval
i need to create trigger to read the needapproval values in the inserted row and check  if it is yes then send an email to the senior 
how can i do this please

db2 connect to mydb -- or whatever your database name is.
db2 update db cfg using smtp_server ':'

Answer (score 0):

Starting with DB2 LUW 9.7 you can use the `UTL_MAIL` system module to send emails, once you have set the `SMTP_SERVER` database configuration parameter. Check out samples in the manual, where it describes the `UTL_MAIL.SEND()` procedure.

Comment: You cannot use this option if you are using DB2 Express-C: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053670.html

Comment: Who said anything about DB2 Express-C?